# Why is typescript disregarding a variable type?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I declared a typed variable that will supposedly hold the data fetched by a service. However, the returned data is not the same type as the variable, yet the variable still accepts the data.

Here is my code:

```
Data: Array<{Currency: string, Rate: number}>;

getData(): void {
  this.DataService.getAll().subscribe(
    (res: Array<any>) => {
      this.Data = res;
    },
    (err) => {
      console.log(err);
    }
  );
}
```

I tried the following but it still didn't work:

```
res: Array<{Currency: string, Rate: number}>
```

**Update**

This is my service

```
getAll(): Observable<Array<{Currency: string, Rate: number}>> {
    return this.http.get(`${this.baseUrl}/data`).pipe(
      map((res) => {
        this.data = res['data'];
        return this.data;
    }),
    catchError(this.handleError));
  }
```

**UPDATE 2**

I found the similar issue here: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/20770

Comment: When you say `any`, TS will not add checks to it as it can be anything

Comment: If you read in the post carefully, I mention that I tried "res: Array<{Currency: string, Rate: number}>"

Comment: Bryan your question is unclear, typescript performs static type-checking pre-transpile to allow for type safe development. The code is transpiled to javascript pre-execution. Therefore there is nothing preventing the variable from accepting the data.

Comment: I typed the data in all stages of its lifecycle. From the service all the way to the component. Why should we bother setting types if typescript is not going to follow them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a model as:

```
export interface CurrencyModel {
  Currency: string,
  Rate: number
}
```

then use this model in response as:

```
Data: CurrencyModel[];

getData(): void {
  this.DataService.getAll().subscribe(
    (res: CurrencyModel[]) => {
      this.Data = res;
    },
    (err) => {
      console.log(err);
    }
  );
}
```

`getAll` should return `Observable<CurrencyModel[]>`

Comment: As mentioned in my comment to Titan, I have tried something similar and added in the Update Section of my post. but thanks

Comment: @Bryan did you try by adding type in `get` method as well like `return this.http.get<CurrencyModel[]>(...`?

Comment: I did now yes. I guess i'll have to force the cast in the SQL and give up on typescript

Comment: @Bryan I saw in edited post you are returning `this.curve_data` but assigning response data in `this.data`.

Comment: I corrected it. I had to replace all the curve_data with data for simplification but forgot that one sorry. nice perception!

Comment: After doing some research (see update number 2 in the post, turns out ur method is the preferred)

Answer (score 0):

Because there is no type safety at runtime.

Remember TypeScript is translated into JavaScript at compile time. And at that point, all bets are off.

If you want to ensure some sort of type safety I recommend using something for API documentation with tooling for automated code generation like OpenAPI with swagger.

Comment: How I read this answer: There are no types at runtime, the type system is meaningless abandon all hope . There is still value to good types IMO.

Comment: No, at all:). I love TypeScript for someone with more of a backend experience it is a godsend. And it generally does it's job. Except for the point of contact between the client and a server. Say what you want about SOAP those problems did not exist there. With super strict schema validation. etc...

Comment: Or GraphQL. With TypeScript code-generation based on the schema from your server, you can have an end-to-end typed API, even supporting nullable/non-nullable types if you work with TypeScript's `strictNullChecks` mode. In my applications, if I make a breaking change in the GraphQL API, the client ends up with a compile-time error that I have to fix. Even if I use a property I did not ask in my query, boom, compilation error too. Working exclusivley with typed languages, even if the types don't exist at runtime, will make you pretty safe.

Comment: Wow, I did not know that. Thanks, man. I have no experience with GraphQL. But that convenience me that I should try it.

Answer (score 0):

`any` is by definition assignable to anything. So `Array<any>` will be assignable to any other array type. I would avoid `any` at all cost. If you truly don't know the type of somethign use `unknown` instead and use explicit assertions as needed, better explicit assertions rather than silent `any` assignments.

```
Data: Array<{Currency: string, Rate: number}>;

getData(): void {
  this.DataService.getAll().subscribe(
    (res: Array<unknwon>) => {
      this.Data = res as Array<{Currency: string, Rate: number}>;
    },
    (err) => {
      console.log(err);
    }
  );
}
```

Ideally `getAll()` should return `Observable<Array<{Currency: string, Rate: number}>>`. The no type annotations would be necessary on `res` and it would all be type safe.

Comment: I tried adding "Observable<Array<{Currency: string, Rate: number}>>" but no luck, I even tried "res: Array<{Currency: string, Rate: number}>"

Answer (score 0):

TypeScript is an extension on top of JavaScript that provides type support *for the process of writing code*. Anyways, all your TypeScript code will be converted to pure JavaScript before you can run your program. Thus, after compilation all your types will be lost in reality.

If your returned data *at runtime* do not have the same type as the variable you declared, there is no chance for TypeScript to warn you or prevent this. This is because TypeScript can only check **static types**, not **dynamic types** like if you receive a server response. You'll need another validation mechanism to verify your server data correspond to your TypeScript definition.